# How to fetch an image stored at Server in the form of string?

Tags: android

I am doing some king of storing and retrieving operations on image in Android and fortunately I successfully stored an image in Server using Base64 class and some encoding operations in such a way that i convert an image into string and stored that string into my server. Now I want to fetch that image and show it on user interface then what should I do.
Also my stored image is of 8 kb but when converted to string it is converted into some 21500 characters which means 21 Kb is there any other way to store an image?

I am using the following code to store an image on Server

```
           //image=R.drawable.ic_launcher;
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), image);
        ByteArrayOutputStream obj=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bm.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 90, obj);
        byte img[]=obj.toByteArray();
        String str=Base64.encodeToString(img,0);
        List<NameValuePair> lst=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        lst.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "2"));
        lst.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image", str));
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(lst));
```

Can anyone would like to help me... please

Comment: Very simple. Now you should download the base64 string from your server. Then decode it to a bytearray. Then make a Bitmap of that bytearray and finally assign the bitmap to an ImageView. `my stored image is of 8 kb but when converted to string it is converted into some 21500 characters which means 21 Kb ` That is becaouse you use Bitmap. If you would upload your image base64 encoded then is should be about 8 * 1.3 KBytes only.

Comment: How to do this particular thing ?

Comment: Which particular thing? I was speaking about a lot of things that you had to do. Step by step. And i meantioned even more.

Answer (score 0):

It's fine that you are sending Base64 string to server but server should convert the received string into image and should store that image. Whenever client asks for the image, it should return actual URL, not the string!

And use some image libraries like [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/), [Universal image downloader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader), [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) or [Fresco](https://code.facebook.com/posts/366199913563917/introducing-fresco-a-new-image-library-for-android/) library. It would allow you to load images asynchronously and caches the loaded images into the memory so that it would load from that cached image.

Comment: I don't know how to use these library. Can you share some link by which I can Figure it out?

Comment: @AnkitArora Go through the library documentation given in each libraries!